# How to Use a List View's ListView_SetItemCount?

Tags: winapi, listview

How exactly are you supposed to use the [ListView_SetItemCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775093.aspx) function for a *non-virtual* list view in Win32?

I've looked at the documentation, but I still can't figure out:

- Whether I'm supposed to call `ListView_SetItem` instead of `ListView_InsertItem` to add an item, after calling `ListView_SetItemCount`.
- Why neither of the above approaches seems to accelerate adding a large number of items (around a few hundred) to a list view. :(

Any ideas?

Comment: @Hans: Oh really? I thought there was more to it than just allocating memory... that seems a bit less useful than I thought, considering that lists just amortize the cost over the newer items anyway, by doubling the size each time. I've tried `WM_SETREDRAW` to improve the speed, which helps -- but only when I'm adding items, not removing them. I thought this might be more helpful but it isn't... any thoughts on how to make `ListView_DeleteAllItems` faster?

Comment: @Hans: Never mind, the speed turned out to be a debugger issue. Post your comment as an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same idea as vector::capacity().  It is not going to make a noticeable improvement on a few hundred items.